# Is there a way to get the length of a softened curve with HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I wonder if HighCharts provides a way to get the length of a curve plotted along the serie of points in a x,y chart.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what do you have in mind? You want to know the length of the line between points? Or the length of diagonal in plot area? Do you have an image which will show you what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a series of points. x and y axis are both in meters. HighCharts generates an spline line (a softened curve). I need to know the length of that curve. I could calculate it if I'd have the equation used by HighCharts plot it. It is possible to get that equation/function?

Comment: how the spline is rendered you can find in the core code: https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js and here I prepared a demo where you can debug the function: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nwuvscLh/